# chart with threshold in power bi

Tags: charts, powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I need to have a chart in power bi as shown in the figure. I the value is a measure which shows the ratio and I have to threshold, less than 80 green, between 80 and 100 yellow and upper than that red. How I can set this chart?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign multiple color for a single bar. **Alternatively**, you can think about Bullet chart where you can set your color for different scales in a bar and then plot your value in that bar as shown in the below image-

[image]

Here Green, Yellow and Red portion is just your targets which is known as Good, Very Good in Bullet chart. The Black middle bar is your data value and here it is indicating that the value belongs to Yellow zone.

Comment: in this chart, is it possible to show the value of sales in different years? or it contains one line?

Comment: One line per bullet chart. But it can generate one bullet chart per year or category dynamically.

Comment: you can generate one line/bullet-chart per year, no issue.